# Download all type of images with webclient including svg

Tags: c#, image, webclient

Hi I'm trying to download all images from different sites using webclient in a console application.
Sometime the site may contain svg as well. I'm using webclient to download images which are working fine but when svg is found it gives exception. Now i want a method which can download all kind of images including png,jpg,bmp,svg
here my working code

```
string fileName = @"fileName1.jpg";
string ActualURL = "http://www.somesite.com/themes/lemonade/resources/images/logo.svg";
string pathtoSaveFiles = @"D:\WMCDataStore\km01";
// Create an instance of WebClient   
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0)"); 
var formattedUrl = ActualURL;
var outputPath = Path.Combine(pathtoSaveFiles, fileName);
client.DownloadFile(new Uri(formattedUrl), outputPath);
```

Comment: What type of Exception is thrown?

Comment: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Comment: WebClient doesn't care about the image type. Setting the User-Agent header also doesn't mattef for dwonloading. *What* is the exception? The status code? Are you sure the URL is correct?

Comment: while the image url when opened in browser works fine

Comment: @skhurams 404 is *very* clear - the URL is wrong. *Maybe* it's a credentials issue and the server doesn't return 403 as it should.

Comment: but when i open in browser i can see image

Comment: some svg images are downloaded but corrupted

Comment: for eg if https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Inbox_font_awesome.svg

Comment: open link in browser works fine but when i download its corrupted using code given above

Comment: Define corrupted. An svg is an XML file and your code is trying to save it with a `jpg` extension. Obviously, you can't read an XML file as if it wer JPG. Besides, the *browser* may be getting redirected from the original URL to another. As for trying to download SharkRotator's theme's, that's a SharePoint site that will display different data to anonymous vs authorized users, and rewrite URLs to target different libraries internally in order to displau friendly URLs. Use Fiddler to see what is actually going on.

Comment: No repro for the wikipedia link. The file is downloaded properly.

Comment: so you are saying that i should save svg with .svg extension